# Storage of Web Application Deployment Settings in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2019, storage, settings

I've had a crash of a Windows 10 development PC with Visual Studio 2019. I could restore everything but the deployment settings for a web application to an IIS webserver. I still have the old HDD with all user settings and alike. But I can't figure out, where these settings are stored. They seem not to be part of the Visual Studio project. Can anybody help me where (what folder, what file) these deployment settings/targets are stored?

I truly believe this issue hasn't been asked before, my apologies it if was. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, hours of hours later, I found out the following and solved the issue:

1. The configuration *is* part of the project (C# in my case)
2. The profiles for publishing are stored under: `[Solution]\[Project]\Properties\PublishProfiles\*.pubxml` and `*.pubxml.user`
3. When you move your project to another folder or in case the folder name changes, you have to adopt the user config of your project: `[Solution]\[Project]\{Project}.csproj.user` There is a node:
   `<NameOfLastUsedPublishProfile>`, which may contain (not always!) the
   full path to the profile. This was the case for me. And since the
   path changed, the profile was there, but simply not shown in the IDE.

Correcting this solved the issue for me. :-)